# IIS Rewrite Rule to redirect to new domain along with querystring parameters

Tags: iis, url-rewrite

I am looking for  IIS Rewrite Rule to redirect from old domain to new domain along with appending querystring parameters to new domain. As I have gone through some articles but I am not getting.
I am trying below Rule but its not working as expected(redirecting to new domain without querystring parameters)

```
<rewrite>
          <rules>
              <rule name="AllURLRedirect" stopProcessing="true">
                  <match url="http://olddomain.com/\b([-a-zA-Z0-9()@:%_\+.~#?&amp;//=]*)" />
                  <action type="Redirect" url="https://www.newdomain.com/{C:1}" redirectType="Permanent" />
              </rule>
          </rules>
</rewrite>
```

Please help me.

Thank you

Comment: If using a CDN (like Cloudflare and Akamai) it may be preferred to place the redirects in that system.

Comment: I am trying with IIS Rewrite Rule and in my local sitecore dev website.

Answer (score 1):

You have to add `appendQueryString="true"` to your `<action>` tag:

```
<rule name="AllURLRedirect" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="http://olddomain.com/\b([-a-zA-Z0-9()@:%_\+.~#?&amp;//=]*)" />
    <action appendQueryString="true" type="Redirect" url="https://www.newdomain.com/{C:1}" redirectType="Permanent" />
</rule>
```